# JAAS - why are my .jsp import's not working?

Tags: java, jsp, jaas

I have the below JSP file:

```
<%@page import="RdbmsLoginModule, PassiveCallbackHandler" %>
<%@page import="SessionLoginContext" %>
<%@page import="javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext, java.util.*" %>
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>

<!-- 
index.jsp: Simple JSP page to test a session-based LoginContext.
-->

<%
if(request.getParameter("user")==null) {
%>
<form action="jaas.jsp" method="POST">
    <input type=text name=user value=""><br>
    <input type=text name=pass value=""><br>
    <input type=submit value=submit>
</form>
<%
} else {
// just so you can see the debug messages
//System.setOut(new PrintStream(response.getOutputStream()));

String user = request.getParameter("user");
String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

PassiveCallbackHandler cbh = new PassiveCallbackHandler(user, pass);

SessionLoginContext lc = new SessionLoginContext("Example", cbh);

session.setMaxInactiveInterval(10); // 10 second timeout

// Setting the SessionLoginContext object in the Session 
// will trigger the valueBound() method in the object which 
// calls login() on the SessionLoginContext. Having set the 
// timeout to 10 seconds, the valueUnbound() method will be 
// called after 10 seconds of inactivity and log the user out.
//
session.setAttribute("loginContext", lc);

Iterator it = lc.getSubject().getPrincipals().iterator();
   while(it.hasNext()) out.println("authenticated principal: " + it.next().toString() + "<br>");

    it = lc.getSubject().getPublicCredentials(Properties.class).iterator();

  while (it.hasNext()) 
    out.println(it.next().toString());

  lc.logout();
 }
 %>
```

And I keep getting the following error:

```
 HTTP Status 500 -

 type Exception report

 message

 descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

 exception

 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

 PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
 string:///index_jsp.java:6: '.' expected

 PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
 string:///index_jsp.java:6: ';' expected

 PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
 string:///index_jsp.java:7: class, interface, or enum expected

 PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
 string:///index_jsp.java:8: '.' expected

 PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
 string:///index_jsp.java:8: ';' expected

 PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
 string:///index_jsp.java:9: class, interface, or enum expected
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: You seem to be experiencing a great deal of keyboard malfunction too...

Comment: Sorry dudes. . . it just drives me crazy when things don't work right; or better yet when I can't get them to work right.  My bad :)

Comment: This is one of many reasons why embedding Java in your JSPs is a bad idea - it's a pain in the arse to debug.

Comment: -1 because you didn't cleanup the garbage yourself in spite of Bozho's comment and also because this is not the first time that you posted a question this astonishing way (and thus clearly learnt nothing from all the previous cleanup edits).

Comment: Honestly, I never noticed anyone saying anything about my caps and punctuation before. . . or maybe since I code all night every night I just never noticed. Sleep deprivation does weird thing you know. . . but really I don't want to get scolded anymore so how bout if I leave the caps and just use one exclamation point and question mark :)  But really by the time I have gotten frustrated enough to ask for help I am pretty much wiggin out. . .

Comment: But seriously, thank you to everyone at StackOverflow for all of your help over the last few months as I progress to becoming a half way decent coder.  I am pretty sure that when I become a fully competent, I will no doubt do the same for the other newbies :)  You guys r da bomb!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out... was really silly when I think about it.  I had to reference the other files by giving them their own folder, so to get my login screen to open it had to modify the above code as follows:

```
<%@page import="RdbmsLoginModule.RdbmsLoginModule,PassiveCallbackHandler.PassiveCallbackHandler" %>         

<%@page import="SessionLoginContext.SessionLoginContext" %>
```

**Furthermore**
To get those other classes to function properly, I had to put:

```
  package RdbmsLoginModule;// in the RdbmsLoginModule class
  package PassiveCallbackHandler; //in the PassiveCallbackHandler class

  etc. . . .
```

Rookie stuff I know, but hey I'm a rookie. . . I'll never make that mistake again (at least and not know how to correct it:)

Thanks everybody for trying to help.

Comment: Good catch. In java the way the system finds a class [kinda] is by treating each . as a different directory. So some where there is a java/lang folder that corresponds to the java.lang package. Every java class should be in itsown file in a rectory coressponding to the package name (the file name should be the same as the class name.) Finally if you are writting your own code create a package correspongin to a domain you control I.e. google packages their code as com.google...

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a long shot, but try and remove the space between RdbmsLoginModule and PassiveCallbackHandler. So it looks like :

```
import="RdbmsLoginModule,PassiveCallbackHandler"
```